# How to programmatically dereference pointer?

Tags: c

A weird interview question I had yesterday

Given a `void *p` pointer, and a int `a = 1;` how to dereference to any level pointers?

For example,

if input is 1, then you can get the data by `*(int *)p`

if input is 2, then you can get the data by `**(int **)p`

if input is 3, then you can get the data by `***(int ***)p`

but what if the input is `n` ? how can you get the data by `*xN(int *xN)p` ?

I completely had no idea.

Comment: This kinda reminds me of this: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int dereference(void *p, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p = *((void **) p);
    }

    return (int)p;
}
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all tested, but I think this recursive solution is approximately right:

```
int get_pointer(void* p, int n)
{
    if (n==1) return *p;
    return get_pointer((void*)(*(int*)p), n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: You could use either a for loop or a recursive function that runs `input` times, and dereference a pointer once each time through the loop, passing the result on to the next iteration.